# Typescript Extend utility why its extracting instead of full object

Tags: typescript

I see the code for Extract

```
type x = 'abc' | 'def' | 32;
type x2 = Extract<x, number>;
// ^? type x2: 32
```

The code for Extract is
`type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never`

But if I try like this, it returns never

```
type x2 = x extends number ? x : never;
// ^? type x2: never
```

I am not able grasp the concept here,when `T extends U` is true it returns T, in the above example T is x and if the condition is true should't it return x? i.e. `'abc' | 'def' | 32`??

Answer (score 3):

When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types))

So when you use `Extract<x, number>`, since `Extract` is a generic and conditional type it goes something like this :

```
type x2 = Extract<'abc',number> | Extract<'def', number> | Extract<32, number>;
```

which is : `never | never | 32 = 32`

But when using a type that is not generic, it becomes :

```
type x2 = ('abc' | "def" | 32) extends number ? ('abc' | "def" | 32) : never;
```

which will be `never`. By the way for additional information you can check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) out.